# Is `[<var> in <distributed variable>]` equivalent to `forall`?

Tags: syntax, chapel

I noticed something in a snippet of code I was given:

```
var D: domain(2) dmapped Block(boundingBox=Space) = Space;
var A: [D] int;
[a in A] a = a.locale.id;
```

Is `[a in A]` equivalent to `forall a in A a = a.locale.id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the most part, yes.  In Chapel, `[a in A] expr` can be thought of as a shorthand for `forall a in A do expr`.  However, there is a slight difference in that if `A` does not support parallel iteration, the `forall` form will generate a compile-time error whereas the `[a in A]` form will fall back to serial iteration.

With respect to the title of this question, note that this behavior is independent of whether or not `A` is distributed.  For example, you could also write `[i in 1..n]` rather than `forall i in 1..n do` even though ranges like `1..n` are never distributed in Chapel.

Array types in Chapel, like `[D] real` can similarly be read as "for all indices in `D`, allocate an element of type `real`."