# Calculate rowSums in Chapel for a matrix

Tags: chapel

Continuing my Chapel adventures...

I have a matrix A.

```
var idx = {1..n};
var adom = {idx, idx};
var A: [adom] int;
//populate A;

var rowsums: [idx] int;
```

What is the most efficient way to populate rowsums?

Comment: SO won't let me make edits of less than six characters, but note that the curly brackets in the declaration of `idx` are probably unintended (they suggest that `adom` is an associative domain whose indices are themselves 1D domains rather than the 2D domain that I think you intended).

Comment: Also, as a general comment—when you declare domains whose index sets you don't plan to change, making them `const` rather than `var` provides helpful semantic information to the compiler's optimizations (e.g., "you will never have to reallocate arrays declared in terms of this domain").  Chapel doesn't do a ton of optimizations for const domains at present, but will do more and more as time goes on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *most efficient* solution is hard to define. However, here is one way to compute `rowsums` that is both parallel and elegant:

```
config const       n = 8;          // "naked" n would cause compilation to fail
const indices = 1..n;              // tio.chpl:1: error: 'n' undeclared (first use this function)
const adom = {indices, indices};
var A: [adom] int;

// Populate A
[(i,j) in adom] A[i, j] = i*j;

var rowsums: [indices] int;


forall i in indices {
  rowsums[i] = + reduce(A[i, ..]);
}

writeln(rowsums);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY4xDoMwDAB3v8IjtCioW1XUgR90RwxRCK1RSFCAMiDenppCpijn88nqIwdtQlDOtvRGfsYJLT7xXsDxIduQ0iOjmxA2Utm4ntF6TrOobQV8pcfygdWu1MynAiDP8eWG2chJYwlVQlmX8ggPp6wow67mHl06tveCd8s49yN3znJMtc5LY5D29XjbChgXKto7V/S6mZVO/mkh6rSADWDxNGljk9NlGMIP)

This is utilizing the [+ reduction](http://chapel.cray.com/docs/master/primers/reductions.html) over [array slices](http://chapel.cray.com/docs/master/primers/slices.html) of `A`.

Note that both the `forall` and `+ reduce` introduce parallelism to the program above. It may be more efficient to only use a `for` loop, avoiding task-spawning overhead, if the size of `indices` is sufficiently small.

Comment: Can you explain this line? `[(i,j) in adom] A[i, j] = i*j;`  And what if indices is really big? What then?

Comment: There's a [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728540/is-var-in-distributed-variable-equivalent-to-forall) for that! It's short-hand for `forall (i,j) in adom do A[i, j] = i*j;`

Comment: I'll mention that there's a longstanding intention to add "partial reductions" to the language (as in prior languages like ZPL) which have the effect of reducing a subset of a rectangular domain's dimensions.  This is likely to result both in a more succinct description of the computation as well as a more efficient implementation, particularly for sparse or distributed arrays.  I believe the current proposed syntax is something like `+ reduce (resultShape=[1..n, 1]) A`

Comment: For large arrays, you'd definitely want the `forall` instead of `for`. If the array needed to be distributed over nodes, we could distribute `A` and `rowsums` with the `Block` distribution (row-wise).

Comment: Would be great to benchmark the distributed-mode test either. Btw, have you thought about a Cray-hosted replica of a hosted-[Chapel]-IDE? `<TiO>-IDE` environment is granted to be freely downloaded and populated on such a "home-base" kind of infrastructure, plus the administrative restrictions may be removed and thus may provide for both the **distributed-computing** infrastructure and need not have a 60-second limit, before a tested piece of code gets administratively `kill`-ed. What does Cray Chapel-Team think about this way of moving REPL-alike IDE efforts right to a fully working system?

Answer (score 1):

### A few hints
[to make the code actually run-live](https://tio.run/##7Zjfb9owEMff81eceCkwIHF@EaCthDakTZPWbqXaA0NVlpjhLnGyxBmVpv3t7MyviUFrWhGe5gekJPbd5y53/joEUz@l0Xyu16F52LgZDG@v8ff18N3Vh@bthzeDT83h4GbYbNZ1KHIKQxbTnnYkgz/9DPwbkaSf@8PXb@9uBh@7CwdZWR6u@582HjRd57kAxkMW0BwugLRavAePDF0H3gUxzegMfAiSOGWRL1jCgWZZgk5yKHhIJ4zT8BET50N2ddlsAgTTNOqS7nJlF8742WJtEPkZLq5OWIZcMtliynKYFDyQjmr7gL1NHLH/cMfCB7yNg5iW7bi9/XHklMY5iAS@oockgYkvACYYwxLw3ZuBfOhHURL4gj4RB@izzE9TmuV6sKi0LkQYP7hdMG3bbcN7FkU01IJkBxDANjpubx87gEc65oHsUcK/7bJHFNMkICs4jLCoxpD6mdhmH04pZPRHQdE9fQgoDTH1Am@6BjpBYrzCOsGAYrTk4@UMX7GgWcw4ZiXcS05cy7OPRo7FuiKX8w/JOjEN29rO@la1rGixZpYPAfwwiQEf/lrNa6wX/O5psnf6XRjJOWO8L3DdqMoa9zW8gOXd/og14H6MFlj9vrcb9XWSFpGsov6oMdYWJrNklhdxjoZXrta2D2/5dePvbfntDaWVC8xgtdbTZK6Xg0n@dWJ@Pdbu@8xrsMYfMRn0K6yhsAhodZGHVmtc6x1g5Dc8YzxmpKxsJalMFlrX4HnjfNfDpazc7/Kh43mmDaMCXzZWuSxvtu7NOAkprF6OBzSiMeUiB9xZN51xTBTbc9ueq0Rx7dJRiEE6nY6hQiFm@VkxDWK4nhLFdNzSUWzi2J22EsUhZukonumiSKlQiGGWXivE8RzLMFQouP2XXiuWRUwsFRWKlPfymxkH130FijxOHAdFzr94xoC6rpWha3gy2NI1PKv91zVFtja6dqza8wzT2qm8xZntxIrmEcdVgpxAz6C9T83@ATmFmoHnYscrQE6hZcQhlq0COYWSEUyIqkZOoWNgGW6bKEBOoWLEcCxl@55Cw8yOaVqqYn1CwV4mSdosY4JGvLre9hubiCpf@BO4lca/Xww08tOchtXF3yot@XPLmchbMQuyZPklnUOtARWFSqPl1eepnLs32MrLKOX@/3LK7TdxCOXf4kDB0ebzPw) in both `SEQ` and `PAR` mode:

Besides a few implementation details, the above stated @bencray's **assumption** about the assumed overhead costs for a **`PAR`** setup, which may favor a purely serial processing in a **`SEQ`** setup, **was not experimentally confirmed.** It is fair to also note here, that a distributed mode was not tested on [**live `<TiO>-IDE`**](https://tio.run/##7ZhNb9s4EIbv@hWDXGKntiVSH5bstoDRGtiiQJM2DvbgNQqtRK@ZlSitRNUBiv72dOiPFK6d0AksnZYHA5LImWdGM3xpRYswZ8n9vXkB3ePG9Xhyc4W/7yYfLj91bz69H3/pTsbXk273woSqZDDhKRsaJzL4LSwgvJZZ/udo8u6Pr9fjz4OVg6IuD1ejLw8eDNMUpQQuYh6xEt4A6fXEEB4ZpgliAHJRsCWEEGVpzpNQ8kwAK4oMnZRQiZjNuWDxIyZeT/jl224XIFrkyYAM1isHcC7OV2ujJCxwcWvOC@RSyZYLXsK8EpFy1D4E7D/EkYZ3X3l8h7dxEGo7rjc8HEfJWFqCzOBv9JBlMA8lwBxjWAN@eD9WD8MkyaJQsifiAHNZhHnOitKMVpU2gATjB28A1HG8PnzkScJiI8r2AAEcK/CGh9gBfBLQI9mTTPyzz54wTJOEohIwxaKaQR4Wcpd9smBQsP8qhu7ZXcRYjKmXeNOz0AkS4xXWCQaUoqUQL5f4iiUrUi4wK/FBcuLZvnMycizWDbmaf0zWCbUcezfrO9WyocWaWT8ECOMsBXz4fTOvs13wY2io3hkNYKrmzPC@xHXTFu/ctvEC1ndHU96B2xla4Be3w/2or7K8SlQVjaadmbEyWWTLskpLNLxxtbV9fMtvG/9gy@9uKL1SYgZb7aGhcr0eXPFvE/P9sXY/ZN6ALf6Uq6BfYQ3FVcRaqzz0erP28AgjP@AZ4zEjdWUry1Wy0LoBzxuv9z28VZX777qng74N0wpfNla5Km@@7c00ixlsXg4FlrCUCVkC7qwPnXFSFOp7hOhRnAZQXN@njh7Frx/F8b2@72lRvPqzQiwSBIGlQyG0/qxQi1ier0Whrlc7ikNcJ@hrUVxSfwf51EPp1qEQi9ZeK8T1XduydCgoirXXim0TiqWiQ1GHngb2FQBhhhoUdcg6DYqa/@YZAy5Mow61x/PSjtrjCfZ/tddka6v2p9zAKbH39XV1mG1Y6n0rcPUgThMg1NaDNCDzPnE9LUgDIg/9QxL/G0gTEg@@h9ugBqQJgScusR0dSBPyTjAhuhppQtzBtry@bh9pQtqJ5dra9m1C2GlAqa0r1idk/WU6bSwLLlkiWlst7DxEdPaXeAL3rPP7n0uWhHnJ4tbqC1xP/dwILsteyqMiW390KaHdgTPN0QUtb75kqLkHgz17GaUSxZdT7r6JYyh/FQeqsHF//xM) due to obvious reasons, whereas a small-if-not-tiny-scale distributed implementation is by far more an oxymoron, than a scientifically meaningful experiment to run.

---

### Facts matter

A `rowsums[]` processing, even at a smallest possible scale of **`2x2`**, was in the **`SEQ`** mode yet slower, than the same for **`256x256`** in the **`PAR`** mode.

**Good job, [chapel](/questions/tagged/chapel) Team**, indeed cool results on optimum alignment for harnessing the compact silicon resources to the max in **`PAR`**!

For records on exact run-time performance, ( ref. self-documented tables ) below, or do not hesistate to visit the live-IDE-run ( ref.'d above ) and experiment on your own.

Readers may also recognise extrinsic noise on small-scale experimentations, as O/S- and hosted-IDE-related processes intervene with resources-usage and influence onto the `<SECTION-UNDER-TEST>` runtime performance via adverse CPU / Lx-CACHE / memIO / process / et al conflicts, which fact exludes these measurements from being used for some generalised interpretations.

---

### Hope all will enjoy the [chapel](/questions/tagged/chapel) lovely `[TIME]` results
<sub>demonstrated across the growing `[EXPSPACE]`-scaled computing landscapes</sub>

```
/* ---------------------------------------SETUP-SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/ use Time;
/* ---------------------------------------SETUP-SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/ var aStopWATCH_SEQ: Timer;
/* ---------------------------------------SETUP-SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/ var aStopWATCH_PAR: Timer;

//nst max_idx =    123456;                   // seems to be too fat  for <TiO>-IDE to allocate                  <TiO>--   /wrappers/chapel: line 6: 24467 Killed
const max_idx =      4096;
//nst max_idx =      8192;                   // seems to be too long for <TiO>-IDE to let it run [SEQ] part     <TiO>--  The request exceeded the 60 second time limit and was terminated
//nst max_idx =     16384;                   // seems to be too long for <TiO>-IDE to let it run [PAR] part too <TiO>--   /wrappers/chapel: line 6: 12043 Killed
const indices = 1..max_idx;

const   adom  = {indices, indices};
var A: [adom] int;

[(i,j) in adom] A[i, j] = i*j;               // Populate A[,]

var rowsums: [indices] int;

/* ---------------------------------------------SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/ aStopWATCH_SEQ.start();
for       i in indices {                     // SECTION-UNDER-TEST--
  rowsums[i] = + reduce(A[i, ..]);           // SECTION-UNDER-TEST--
}                                            // SECTION-UNDER-TEST--
/* ---------------------------------------------SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/ aStopWATCH_SEQ.stop();

/* 
                                               <SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took     8973 [us] to run in [SEQ] mode for    2 elements on <TiO>-IDE
                                               <SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took    28611 [us] to run in [SEQ] mode for    4 elements on <TiO>-IDE
                                               <SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took    58824 [us] to run in [SEQ] mode for    8 elements on <TiO>-IDE
                                               <SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took   486786 [us] to run in [SEQ] mode for   64 elements on <TiO>-IDE
                                               <SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took  1019990 [us] to run in [SEQ] mode for  128 elements on <TiO>-IDE
                                               <SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took  2010680 [us] to run in [SEQ] mode for  256 elements on <TiO>-IDE
                                               <SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took  4154970 [us] to run in [SEQ] mode for  512 elements on <TiO>-IDE
                                               <SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took  8260960 [us] to run in [SEQ] mode for 1024 elements on <TiO>-IDE
                                               <SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took 15853000 [us] to run in [SEQ] mode for 2048 elements on <TiO>-IDE
                                               <SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took 33126800 [us] to run in [SEQ] mode for 4096 elements on <TiO>-IDE
                                               <SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took      n/a [us] to run in [SEQ] mode for 8192 elements on <TiO>-IDE

   ============================================ */


/* ---------------------------------------------SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/ aStopWATCH_PAR.start();
forall    i in indices {                     // SECTION-UNDER-TEST--
  rowsums[i] = + reduce(A[i, ..]);           // SECTION-UNDER-TEST--
}                                            // SECTION-UNDER-TEST--
/* ---------------------------------------------SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/ aStopWATCH_PAR.stop();
/*
                                               <SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took  12131 [us] to run in [PAR] mode for    2 elements on <TiO>-IDE
                                               <SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took   8095 [us] to run in [PAR] mode for    4 elements on <TiO>-IDE
                                               <SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took   8023 [us] to run in [PAR] mode for    8 elements on <TiO>-IDE
                                               <SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took   8156 [us] to run in [PAR] mode for   64 elements on <TiO>-IDE
                                               <SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took   7990 [us] to run in [PAR] mode for  128 elements on <TiO>-IDE
                                               <SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took   8692 [us] to run in [PAR] mode for  256 elements on <TiO>-IDE
                                               <SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took  15134 [us] to run in [PAR] mode for  512 elements on <TiO>-IDE
                                               <SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took  16926 [us] to run in [PAR] mode for 1024 elements on <TiO>-IDE
                                               <SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took  30671 [us] to run in [PAR] mode for 2048 elements on <TiO>-IDE
                                               <SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took 105323 [us] to run in [PAR] mode for 4096 elements on <TiO>-IDE
                                               <SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took 292232 [us] to run in [PAR] mode for 8192 elements on <TiO>-IDE

   ============================================ */



writeln( rowsums,
        "\n <SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took ", aStopWATCH_SEQ.elapsed( Time.TimeUnits.microseconds ), " [us] to run in [SEQ] mode for ", max_idx, " elements on <TiO>-IDE",
        "\n <SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took ", aStopWATCH_PAR.elapsed( Time.TimeUnits.microseconds ), " [us] to run in [PAR] mode for ", max_idx, " elements on <TiO>-IDE"
         );
```

### This is what makes [chapel](/questions/tagged/chapel) so great

Thanks for developing and improving such great computing tool for the HPC.

Comment: you have parceled together quite a few bits over SO, you should blog these results somewhere and be the first voice of the Chapel community.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment, Brian. IMHO, Brad & his Cray-[Chapel]-Team has made immense amount of work during the recent about a decade and half so as to get us to the point, where we see [Chapel] and its performance today. My hat is raised for that accumulated amount of work & unique HPC expertise created. **Keep Walking!**