# Custom rowSums of a Matrix in Chapel

Tags: sparse-matrix, chapel

Following up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45724161/calculate-rowsums-in-chapel-for-a-matrix).  I have a Matrix (yes, I do) which will be large and sparse.

```
A = [
     [0,   0, 0, 1.2, 0]
     [0,   0, 0, 0,   0]
     [3.5, 0, 0, 0,   0]
     [0    7, 0, 0,   0]
]
```

And I want to create a vector `v` that has the sum `v[j] = v[j,] * log(v[j,])` for each row in `A`

I believe there is an iterator like `[x * log(x) for x in row] do...` but I'm having a hard time finding the syntax.  One particular bugaboo is to avoid taking `log(0)`, so maybe an `if` statement in the iterator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe there is an iterator like [x * log(x) for x in row] do... but I'm having a hard time finding the syntax.

Instead of creating an iterator, we can create a function to compute `x * log(x)` and just pass an array (or array slice) to it, allowing [promotion](http://chapel.cray.com/docs/master/users-guide/datapar/promotion.html) to take care of the rest.

Instead of doing a `+ reduce` over the array slices like we did before,

```
forall i in indices {
  rowsums[i] = + reduce(A[i, ..]);
}
```

We can do a `+ reduce` over a promoted operation on the array slices, like this:

```
forall i in indices {
  rowsums[i] = + reduce(logProduct(A[i, ..]));
}
```

where `logProduct(x)` can include an if-statement handling the special case of `0`, as you mentioned above.

Putting this all together looks something like this:

```
config const n = 10;

proc main() {
  const indices = 1..n;
  const Adom = {indices, indices};
  var A: [Adom] real;

  populate(A);

  var v = rowSums(A);

  writeln('matrix:');
  writeln(A);

  writeln('row sums:');
  writeln(v);
}


/* Populate A, leaving many zeros */
proc populate(A: [?Adom]) {
  forall i in Adom.dim(1) by 2 do // every other row
    forall j in Adom.dim(2) by 3 do // every third column
      A[i, j] = i*j;
}

/* Compute row sums with custom function (logProduct) */
proc rowSums(A: [?Adom] ?t) {
  var v: [Adom.dim(1)] t;

  [i in v.domain] v[i] = + reduce(logProduct(A[i, ..]));

  return v;
}

/* Custom function to handle log(0) case */
proc logProduct(x: real) {
  if x == 0 then return 0;
  return x * log(x);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit of how promotion helps here?

Comment: In a nutshell, if you pass an iterable object of element-type `t` to a function that expects type `t`, then the function will be called on each element (in parallel!). I added a link to the documentation (http://chapel.cray.com/docs/master/users-guide/datapar/promotion.html) in an edit for further explanation.